# how can I hide my system folders?

Tags: vsftpd

I want to hide my system folders when I access to ftp.however it doesnt, how can I fix it?

[ftp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meEhW.png)

Answer (score 3):

set

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Read the [docs](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html), be educated